# Is it ok to cover this cement patch with lime mortar?

Tags: cement, lime

I previously asked about a patch on a  deep hole which has been giving off a strong odour.  In the comments people mentioned that the cement had probably been mixed with other materials hence an unusually strong odour.

[image]

I am a bit sensitive to paint, etc., so instead of painting over it I thought of using this [lime based product](https://www.lime.org.uk/general-purpose-filler-ty-mawr.html) to simply go over it slightly and seal in the smell.   I have been told it definitely doesn’t gas off smell/odour.  The description for the product is:

“This is a non-shrink, ready mixed mortar made with natural hydraulic lime, siliceous and calcareous sand (0-0.6mm) and additives. Suitable for repairing or restoring cement renders, lime plasters and refurbishment work on composite backgrounds.”

Will it be ok to just cover it or might it introduce other problems? I take it the original cement can be covered straight away thought it’s been a few days already drying.

Thanks.

Comment: The product may not smell but it may well allow the smell to pass through...

Comment: It may seal the smells in well enough for most people, but as you seem to be highly sensitive to odor, it may not be good enough for you. Since we don't know just how sensitive your nose it, I think the only reasonable option is for you to try it out. Buy some, apply it to a piece of disposable wood and set that in your house for a day or two to see if you smell anything from it. If not, apply it to your patch and see if it stops the odors satisfactorily for _you_. If it does, _great!_, if not, well, you'll have to try another product on top of that.

Comment: @Freeman considering it is made of lime,sAnd etc wouldn’t this be strong enough to block most odours?  Thanks.